# I'm stupid and added tranny fluid to my coolant tank. What can I expect?

Tags: automatic-transmission, coolant

Title pretty much says it all. I'm a computer guy, not a car guy. I saw a bunch of red fluid coming out of my vehcile, assumed it was tranny fluid. Turns out it was antifreeze. This means the bit of tranny fluid I put in the reservoir that was leaking was a mistake.

What can I expect to happen to my car?

Comment: Too bad there isn't a Ctrl-Z for cars... :(  Good luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you haven't run the car yet then just drain out the reservoir.  If you have run the car then some of the fluid might have started to circulate through the cooling system.  If so, flush your coolant.

A small amount should not affect the car's ability to stay cool.  So this is not that critical, but you definitely don't want to let your engine overheat.

Answer (score 1):

Some guy put tranny fluid in my gmc truck .thank god it wasnt alot .anyway my mechanic flushed the radiator with straight hose water before the truck was started .and it seems to be ok no overheating. So far thank god